# Can I remove list items using a regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm constructing a selection list like so:

```
var releases = data.suites.split(':');
$.each(releases, function(i, val){
    if (val) {
        var info = val.split('-');
        $('#testList').append('<option value="'+info[0]+'">'+info[1]+'</option>');
    }
});
```

Both the value and text for each entry are preceded with specific text.  Is it possible to remove all items from my list that match this text using jquery and a regex?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you use an [Attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to match the value, you won't even need a regex.

Comment: I don't understand. Remove them from the original string? Exclude them from the `option` elements being created? Remove them from the DOM? Please give a little more detail.

Comment: Yes remove them from both the DOM and the option elements

Comment: Then you can probably do what @FrédéricHamidi suggested before the loop. To exclude them from the options being created, you can use `.indexOf` to see if that text is at the beginning of the string. `if (val && val.indexOf('foobar') !== 0) {...` If the targeted text is at the beginning of the string, the `indexOf` will return the `0` index.

Comment: Something like this:   $('#testList').remove( $('option[name="mytext"]').val() );

Comment: Unfortunately they would need to be removed after the list was complete

Comment: Why after? If you use `.indexOf` to prevent their creation, you should only need to remove the existing ones before the loop.

Comment: `$('#testList').find('option[name^="mytext"]').remove();`

Comment: @user1216398: You're welcome. To make it official, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to prevent the creation of the targeted items, use `.indexOf` in the loop.

If there are existing elements in the DOM to be removed, you can do a DOM selection based on the start of the attribute value.

```
  // Cache DOM selection!!! ;-)
var testlist = $('#testList');

    // remove existing elements where the "name" starts with "some_text"
testlist.find('option[name^="some_text"]').remove();

var releases = data.suites.split(':');
$.each(releases, function(i, val) {

       // Prevent creation when the val starts with "some_text"
    if (val && val.indexOf("some_text") !== 0) {
        var info = val.split('-');
        testlist.append('<option value="'+info[0]+'">'+info[1]+'</option>');
    }
});
```